# React-bootstrap, Rows and Cols, How to make Columns Stack on Mobile?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            Stuff1
          </Col>
          <Col>
            Stuff2
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So on a desktop screen, I get two columns with Stuff1 and Stuff2, which I want.

However, on mobile devices, I don't want two columns, because it looks very squished. Instead I would like the two columns to stack on top of each other like rows instead. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Learn bootstrap first. You will already get your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) by bootstrap and the [respective syntax](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#responsive-grids) used in react-strap

Demo code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={6}>
            Stuff1
          </Col>
          <Col sm={6}>
            Stuff2
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flex-direction` attribute of `Row` component must be set to `row`

create a CSS file called `style.css`:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .rowstyle {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row !important;
  }
```

and update the main file:

```
import "style.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row className="rowstyle">
          <Col sm={6}>
            Stuff1
          </Col>
          <Col sm={6}>
            Stuff2
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```